# Write rate drop(POC)

Tags: database, cnosdb

When data is written, the read rate gradually decreases, which in turn decreases the write rate. As a result, the write time is greatly extended
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uugkI.png)

To Reproduce
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

Expected behavior
A clear and concise description of what you expected to happen.

Additional context
Add any other context about the problem here.